# Cant connect from python client to meteor server using python-ddp

Tags: python, meteor, ddp

I am trying to connect meteor server using python-ddp package 
https://github.com/hharnisc/python-ddp

When i run the py file,just nothing happens and programme terminates.Server is running port and everything is correct.

```
   from DDPClient import DDPClient

client = DDPClient('ws://127.0.0.1:3000/websocket')
client.connect()
def connected():
    print("connected")

client.on('connected', connected)
```

I guess python-ddp package is outdated and thats why its not working ? Is there anyone who is using this package to communicate with meteor server  ?

Do you guys recommend any other package/way to communicate with meteor using python client ?

thanks

Comment: What happens if you use the global npm package `wscat` to connect from cli? Besies that, any errors?

Comment: I can connect with wscat.There is no error.If you have python installed,can you try it ? If its same,i will try to communicate using http.